# Three-tier architecture

Tags: database, mobile, client-server, three-tier

I have a mobile application which collects sensor data and processes it before sending it to the server. The server's role is to update or insert data to the appropriate database table, and the database is a central repository where all the data is stored. Can this architecture be called a three-tier architecture please?

Comment: First-tier is your application (UI) ,Second tier can a web service hosted somewhere to handle the data access layer. And Third tier will be your RDBMS( Database Server).

Comment: Yes, but by first-tier is not only UI. It does processing too

Comment: of-course UI layer also have some process units like client interface, data validation, some business decisions etc. But all business logic and database interaction is written in services (IInd layer)

Answer (score 1):

As per your question ,
Your application has three-tier Architecture 
1. Your Application UI.
2. Your webservice or web API part.
3. Database layer where your all database related query stays.